# Make Spring controller multi threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, jquery, spring-mvc, controller

**I am using spring MVC**

```
@Controller
public class AJAXController {

protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AJAXController.class);



@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxGetUomList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
List<JsonOptionsList> ajaxGetUomList(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) long id) {

    JsonOptionsList response=null;
    List<JsonOptionsList> list = null;

    try {

        list= new ArrayList<>();

        InvItemModel itemModel=pt.getById(InvItemModel.class, id);

        List<InvUOMExtendedModel> invUOMModel=pt.getAllByColumnNameId(InvUOMExtendedModel.class,"fko_uome_uom.id", itemModel.getFko_itm_uom().getId());

        for(int i=0; i<invUOMModel.size(); i++){
            response = new JsonOptionsList();
            response.setId(invUOMModel.get(i).getId());
            response.setName(invUOMModel.get(i).getName());
            list.add(response);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error" + ex);
    }

    return list;
}

}
```

I get the UOM LIST using jquery ajax call. Now I want make this controller Multithreaded, Means When Multiple ajax call, send a request to get UOM List , First of All , very first request will entertained. As this process complete then process second request and so on ..

Update Me !

Comment: Controller method is already multi threaded. Maybe your model method getAllByColumnNameId() make other threads wait. The for loop is a waste of time. Why don't you mapping the result to invUOMModel in your model result.

Comment: because sometime there is one to many association between the Model(Entity), then Spring Throws an exception of session close etc etc , because lazy loading not working on jquery json data @Larry.Z